# Convert date to decimal year

Tags: excel

If I have a data in excel formatted as 24-Jan-2016, how do I convert the date so I have it in a decimal format  such as 2016.0000  ( in this case the 0000 would be the month and day in some decimal format)

Comment: Based on a 365 day year? or should one try to determine if leap year and base it on a 366 day year?

Comment: Can you give an example of what 24-Jan-2016 would actually convert to?

Comment: And do you want 1/1/2016 to be `2016.0000` or `12/31/2016` to be `2017.0000`

Comment: Assuming your date is in `A1`, you could try: `=YEARFRAC(1,A1)+1900`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Wow. And to think I wasted 10 minutes trying to write some convoluted formula. You should add that as an answer, IMO.

Comment: Yes I want 1/1/2016 interpreted as 2016.000. Thany you @Cybernetic.nomad that function worked.

Comment: @SelenaChavez You should consider changing your accepted answer - the accepted answer does not yield the same results as cybernetic.nomad's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your date is in A1, you could try:

```
=YEARFRAC(1,A1)+1900
```

It will basically return the number of years between two dates. `1` being January 1st, 1900, you need to add 1900 for the formula to return the same year as your date.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the display, you could use text() formula. The following will display the year in the YYYY.0000 format, assuming your data is in cell A1: 
=TEXT(YEAR(A1),"0.0000")

To display the year, followed by a decimal point, then followed by month and date, two digits for each, you could do: 
=TEXT(YEAR(A1),"0.")&TEXT(MONTH(A1),"MM")&TEXT(DAY(A1),"DD")

Wrapping the whole formula in Value() will convert the output to a number:
=VALUE(TEXT(YEAR(A1),"0.")&TEXT(MONTH(A1),"MM")&TEXT(DAY(A1),"DD"))